# Is query string approach reliable?

Tags: css, browser-cache, updating

I am looking for some effective ways to bypass the cache whenever necessary. In the process of searching for that I have found this [link](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/)

From the referenced post I found that the query string approach may not work when the [squid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29) like proxies are used. I did not test this.

I see that stackoverflow in itself is using the query string approach, below is the screenshot for the same captured before login to the site.

[image]

Would like to know if the query string approach is a reliable solution to push the css and js updates whenever a new software build is released.

Comment: Are you suggesting that squid like _server side_ proxies will return same content  for resources regardless of query string parameters?

Comment: @Ejaz, rather the opposite. According to the link, the content is never cached by squid if a query string is present. I believe it's just a rumor though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's reliable *browser side*, meaning that since the URL is different (because there's a different query parameter), it will fetch a new copy.

*Server side* it depends on your server. Some caching proxies may ignore query parameters for the purpose of determining URL equality. AWS CloudFront for example does so by default. That's always a configurable setting. Since, presumably, you are in charge of the server, you can configure it as needed.